# Undefined Offset : 1 at TCPDF using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I have a problem with TCPDF with codeigniter, This is my whole function code to print pdf :

```
function laporan()
{
    $data_ajuan = $this->pinjaman_m->get_pengajuan_cetak();
    $opsi_val_arr = $this->setting_m->get_key_val();
    foreach ($opsi_val_arr as $key => $value) {
        $out[$key] = $value;
    }

    //var_dump($data_ajuan);
    //exit();
    if ($data_ajuan['total'] == 0) {
        echo 'Data Kosong';
        exit();
    }
    $list = $data_ajuan['rows'];

    $fr_jenis = isset($_REQUEST['fr_jenis']) ? explode(',', $_REQUEST['fr_jenis']) : array();
    $fr_status = isset($_REQUEST['fr_status']) ? explode(',', $_REQUEST['fr_status']) : array();

    $fr_jenis = array_diff($fr_jenis, array(NULL)); // NULL / FALSE / ''
    $fr_status = array_diff($fr_status, array(NULL)); // NULL / FALSE / ''

    $fr_bulan = isset($_REQUEST['fr_bulan']) ? $_REQUEST['fr_bulan'] : '';

    if ($fr_bulan != '') {
        $bln_dari = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fr_bulan . "-01 -1 month"));
        $tgl_dari = substr($bln_dari, 0, 7) . '-21';
        $tgl_sampai = $fr_bulan . '-20';
    } else {
        $tgl_dari = $_REQUEST['tgl_dari'];
        $tgl_sampai = $_REQUEST['tgl_sampai'];
    }


    //$fr_jenis = explode(',', $fr_jenis);
    //$fr_status = explode(',', $fr_status);

    if (!empty($fr_jenis)) {
        $txt_jenis = implode(', ', $fr_jenis);
    } else {
        $txt_jenis = "Semua";
    }
    $status_arr = array(0 => 'Menunggu Konfirmasi', 1 => 'Disetujui', 2 => 'Ditolak', 3 => 'Sudah Terlaksana', 4 => 'Batal');
    if (!empty($fr_status)) {
        $status_rep = str_replace(
            array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4'),
            array('Menunggu Konfirmasi', 'Disetujui', 'Ditolak', 'Sudah Terlaksana', 'Batal'),
            $fr_status
        );
        $txt_status = implode(', ', $status_rep);
        //echo $txt_status; exit();
    } else {
        $txt_status = "Semua";
    }
    //echo $txt_status; exit();
    $this->load->library('Pdf');
    $pdf = new Pdf('L', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->set_nsi_header(TRUE);
    $pdf->AddPage('L');
    $html = '';
    $html .= '
    <style>
        .h_tengah {text-align: center;}
        .h_kiri {text-align: left;}
        .h_kanan {text-align: right;}
        .txt_judul {font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 12px;}
        .header_kolom {background-color: #cccccc; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}
    </style>
    ' . $pdf->nsi_box($text = '<span class="txt_judul">Laporan Data Pengajuan <br></span> <span> Periode ' . jin_date_ina($tgl_dari) . ' - ' . jin_date_ina($tgl_sampai) . ' | Jenis: ' . $txt_jenis . ' | Staus: ' . $txt_status . ' </span> ', $width = '100%', $spacing = '0', $padding = '1', $border = '0', $align = 'center') . '
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="1">
        <tr class="header_kolom" pagebreak="false">
            <th style="width:3%;" >No</th>
            <th style="width:8%;">ID Ajuan</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">NIK</th>
            <th style="width:25%;">Nama</th>
            <th style="width:11%;">Dept</th>
            <th style="width:8%;">Tanggal</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">Nominal</th>
            <th style="width:10%;">Pelunasan</th>
            <th style="width:3%;">Bln</th>
            <th style="width:12%;">Status</th>
        </tr>';
    $no = 1;
    $total_nominal = 0;
    $total_sisa_arr = array();
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        $sisa_tagihan = '-';
        if ($row->jenis != 'Darurat') {
            $sisa_tagihan = $row->sisa_tagihan;
            $total_sisa_arr[$row->anggota_id] = str_replace(',', '', $row->sisa_tagihan);
        }
        $html .= '
        <tr nobr="true">
            <td class="h_tengah">' . $no++ . ' </td>
            <td class="h_tengah">' . $row->ajuan_id . '</td>
            <td class="h_tengah">' . $row->identitas . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->nama . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->departement . '</td>
            <td class="h_tengah">' . $row->tgl_input_txt . '</td>
            <td class="h_kanan">' . $row->nominal . '</td>
            <td class="h_kanan">' . $sisa_tagihan . '</td>
            <td class="h_tengah">' . $row->lama_ags . '</td>
            <td>' . $status_arr[$row->status] . '</td>
        </tr>
        ';
        $total_nominal += str_replace(',', '', $row->nominal);
    }
    $total_sisa = 0;
    foreach ($total_sisa_arr as $val) {
        $total_sisa += $val;
    }

    $html .= '
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="h_kanan"> <strong> Total </strong> </td>
        <td class="h_kanan"><strong> ' . number_format(nsi_round($total_nominal)) . ' </strong></td>
        <td class="h_kanan"><strong> ' . number_format(nsi_round($total_sisa)) . ' </strong></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>';
    $html .= '</table>';

    $html .= '
    <br><br>
    <table width="97%">
    <tr>
        <td class="h_tengah" height="50px" width="40%">Dibuat oleh,</td>
        <td class="h_tengah" width="60%"> ' . $out['kota'] . ', ' . jin_date_ina(date('Y-m-d')) . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="h_tengah"> BENDAHARA </td>
        <td class="h_tengah"> KETUA </td>
    </tr>
    </table>';

    $pdf->nsi_html($html);
    $pdf->Output('pinjam' . date('Ymd_His') . '.pdf', 'I');
}
```

First i got an error in TCPDF.PHP based on what i read because my PHP version not able to support each function, here is the first code

```
while (list($id, $name) = each($style_array[1])) {
    // in case of duplicate attribute the last replace the previous
    $dom[$key]['style'][strtolower($name)] = trim($style_array[2][$id]);
}
```

Got this error Message: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls

Then i change the code using foreach like this code :

```
foreach ($attr_array[1] as $id => $name) {
    // in case of duplicate attribute the last replace the previous
    $dom[$key]['style'][strtolower($name)] = trim($style_array[2][$id]);
}
```

So there is new error like below :
Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Line Number: 16899

am i miss something or can someone help me what can i do, i have been stuck for hours.
appreciate any help thank you !

Comment: Your while/each combination iterated over `$style_array[1]`, but now your foreach loop goes over `$attr_array[1]` ...?

Comment: what code is at Line Number: 16899 ?